# How to route an incoming call when I have multiple phone numbers with the same SIP provider?

Tags: communication, sip, voip, asterisk, telephony

I have a **main** phone number `0120120020` given by my SIP provider for my office. I've recently asked my SIP provider for a **second** phone number `0230230030` on the same SIP account.

I want Asterisk to ring every phones belonging to **Group A** when someone calls the office by dialing the **main** phone number, and I want it to ring every phones belonging to **Group B** if the **second** phone number is dialed instead.

My extensions.conf contains the following lines :

```
[sip-incoming-calls]
exten => s,1,Dial(SIP/10&SIP/11&SIP/12&SIP/20&SIP/21,20,tr)
```

Extensions 10, 11 and 12 belongs to the **Group A**, extensions 20 and 21 belongs to the **Group B**. Every phones are ringing for each incoming calls coming from the **main** and the **second** phone number.

How can I do this with Asterisk 1.8 under CentOS 6.3 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each call, Asterisk sets some variables containing informations about the current incoming call. These informations are useful to act differently if the call is coming from specific country, you can also block bad callers from their phone numbers,...

We are looking for a way to retrieve the DID, which actually means Direct Inward Dialing Number, that's the number dialed by the caller to call your office.

There are two ways to retrieve it :

- By using the `CALLERID(dnid)` variable directly, it's value will be set to **0120120020** or **0230230030**

  ```
  [sip-incoming-calls]
  exten => s,1,Set(thedid=${CALLERID(dnid)})
  ```
- If the above variable is empty, then your SIP provider doesn't send any informations as needed to make Asterisk filling it correctly.

  You can however retrieve the phone number directly from the To field inside the SIP header with `SIP_HEADER(To)`, this variable will contain `<sip:0230230030@sip.provider.com>` when someone calls your office from your **second** phone number.

  ```
  [sip-incoming-calls]
  exten => s,1,Set(thedid=${SIP_HEADER(To)})
  exten => s,2,Set(thedid=${CUT(thedid,@,1)})
  exten => s,3,Set(thedid=${CUT(thedid,:,2)})
  ```

Once you have retrieved the DID inside the variable, you have to set a condition, let's use `GotoIf`. It will result like this in your case :

```
exten => s,4,GotoIf($["${thedid}" = "0120120020"]?6:5)
exten => s,5,GotoIf($["${thedid}" = "0230230030"]?7)
exten => s,6,Dial(SIP/10&SIP/11&SIP/12,20,tr)
exten => s,7,Dial(SIP/20&SIP/21,20,tr)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
[sip-incoming-calls]

exten => s,1,goto(${CUT(CUT(SIP_HEADER(TO),@,1),:,2)},1)

exten => 0120120020,1,Dial(SIP/10&SIP/11&SIP/12,20,tr)

exten => 0230230030,1,Dial(SIP/20&SIP/21,20,tr)
```

Answer (score 1):

easily you can create trunk (seperate dahdi port) and redirect trunk to specific extensions.

Answer (score 1):

ask your voip provider to send the DID number for the incomming calls
then use the below dialplan

```
[sip-incoming-calls] 
exten => _0120120020,1,Dial(SIP/10&SIP/11&SIP/12,tr) 
exten => _0120120020,n,hangup
exten => _0230230030,1,Dial(SIP/20&SIP/21,20,tr) 
exten => _0230230030,n,hangup
```